# Automatic Creation of Java Types from SQL Table

Tags: java, sql, sql2java

I have the *pleasure* of working on a new version of an old application for a new platform (Android). There are quite a large number of rudimentary types of objects in a MySQL database for which I would like to create the local class types as a direct map to the columns in the database tables so that users can download that data, work on it, and update the server with the progress intermittently. It would be fine to store everything in an SQLite DB, but I would prefer having classes to work with.

Is there a tool available to make that process easier, and less prone to error? Is there a generic solution for the local storage/editing/uploading of online mysql table rows?

I have, in the past, simply created the types by hand, and created the corresponding database getting and setting methods by hand- very error prone and tedious work, is there some other way to avoid that extra labor? Would it be wise to make the tools, if they don't exist, similar to the soap style tools we use to create code from WSDLs?

Comment: check sql2java https://github.com/xgp/sql2java

Comment: I will check that out now! Any insight on the negative voting?

Comment: It wasn't me so I don't know.

Comment: No worries! If you have time to post it as an answer that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok I've added an answer. I've also added the appropriate tag in the question. Glad I could help have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [sql2java](https://github.com/xgp/sql2java).

> SQL2JAVA is a free, open source object-relational mapping tool.
>
> It enables Java developers to quickly map a relational database schema
>   to a set of classes.
>
> The generated source code uses standard JDBC methods for persistence,
>   and there is no runtime library required.
>
> Note that 2 formers SQL2JAVA project admin have created SpringFuse, a
>   Java code generator that generates the source code of a complete
>   web-application based on Hibernate, Spring, Spring MVC, Spring
>   Security, etc.